# How can the permissions for all external guests be managed?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups, external-users, sharepoint-permissions

I have a question regarding external guests and their permissions management. I have created a public SharePoint Team Website and created external guests.

I have the following users, which I can use for permissions:

- Owner of WebsiteXY
- Members of WebsiteXY
- Anyone, except external

I would like to map the following authorization structure:

All in my organization and external guests should have reading access to the website. Members should be able to participate normally.

But there is no "External" group... the guests are in my "Members of..." group - so I can't allow guests in isolation.

How can I implement this?

Comment: There is a group for "Everyone" - in addition to the one "Everyone except external users". If you add this to your visitor group you should be covered?

Comment: I only have the entry "Anyone, but external users"

Answer (score 0):

An interesting approach is to add a **Permission level** in *site permissions* for external users so that you can control what they can and cannot do on the site.

For example, here is a screenshot of the permissions that exist in one of my sites. The *Collaborate* permission was created to manage customer activity.

[image]

So you can create a group for external users (clients in my case) and give them the right permission. That's how we managed customer access in a project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new SharePoint Group, and add external users to the new group, grant the new SharePoint Group read permission on the site.

Comment: I dont have the "user" external users... I only have "Anyone, except external"... I also don't want to add every external user individually! For this there must be a general user (like members of..., owners of...)?!

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it sounds as if you do not have permission to add external users. You should consult your Site Collection Administrator, or Office 365 Administrator.

EDIT: based on a comment by @SharePointNewbie, it seems the problem might be [an Azure setting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Office365/Enterprise/collaborate-in-a-site):

> Sharing in Microsoft 365 is governed at its highest level by the
>   organizational relationships settings in Azure Active Directory. If
>   guest sharing is disabled or restricted in Azure AD, this will
>   override any sharing settings that you configure in Microsoft 365.

Comment: I am the Site Collection Administrator... I can also add the individual guest to a specific role, but my question is whether there is a general guest user (analogous to "members of...", "owners of..."). I don't want to have to add all guests to a group manually.

Comment: @SharePointNewbie, edited my answer with more information and a link to Microsoft's page on (what I believe is) your scenario.

Comment: I can invite guests, they create an account and can enter my SharePoint site. I can also address them individually (in the permission settings). I click on "new" and then I can search for name and e-mail in the corresponding field - that's where I find the guests. My question is whether there is a general user for guests. After all, there are also "Members of...", "everyone except external users" which I can add to groups.

Comment: Are you trying to make your SharePoint site available to people who do not have accounts at all, without logging in? I believe that this is not allowed by SharePoint.

Comment: I have created many guest accounts, now I don't want to have to enter them all, I would like to have a general user with whom I can put all of them into one group. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I do understand now, @SharePointNewbie. I agree with the answers below, that you'll need to add all the external users to a group in order to control them together.